# Netbeans swing text field hint list

Tags: swing, netbeans

I want to create text field with hints depending on what the input is (something like google search). Is there a possibility to do it with text field? And if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean Auto-Completion (you have to use a JComboBox):

The easiest way is to use the [SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/) library.

Example:

```
JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox(new Object[] { "One", "Two",
        "Three", "Four", "Five" });
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBox);
combobox.setEditable(true);
```

If you want to do it yourself, read [this](http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/).